# Angular 2 animations (using a different animation library e.g GreenSock Application Platform)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I have been playing around with Angular 2 and it uses its own API to do animations.

Is it now possible to use a library like GSAP to construct the animations but let the API control the states? e.g

```js
  animations: [
    trigger('heroState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        transform: 'scale(1)'
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
        transform: 'scale(1.1)'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
```

Can we do something like this?:

```js
  animations: [
    trigger('heroState', [
      state('inactive'
      })),
      state('active'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', TweenMax.to(this,1,{scale:2, backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc'})),
      transition('active => inactive', TweenMax.to(this,1,{scale:1,backgroundColor: 'pink'})
    ])
  ]
```

I wonder if this type of thing is currently possible in Angular 2 at present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no, since the syntax is part of the Web Animations API and such implementation would not work. The Web Animations API opens the browser’s animation engine to developers and manipulation by JavaScript. This API was designed to underlie implementations of both CSS Animations and CSS Transitions, and leaves the door open to future animation effects.